# Configure wygwam configuration via field parameter?

Tags: safecracker, wygwam, channel-form

Within a channel form, is it possible to override/specify the editor configuration that wygwam uses?

For example:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="post"}
    <label>Post Content</label>
    {field:wygwam_field editor="basic"}
{/exp:channel:form}
```

Basically, I want the users in the CP to have access to the "Full" editor. But users submitting content via the front-end/Channel Form to have a "basic" editor load.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

For developers:

Not easy, the display_field() method from wygwam gets its settings early on. However you maybe able to pluck apart the toolbars in the hook "wygwam_config".

See https://github.com/pixelandtonic/wygwam_super_admin_source for an extension that adds a "source" button for super-admins. You could use that as a basis to remove / set other config options as well (e.g. based on REQ == CP or ACTION or PAGE)

**Edit**: more info http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/wygwam/developers/wygwam_config.html
**Edit2**: even better http://dmlogic.com/blog/managing-wygwams-settings-via-code/